# opencv dft vs. matlab fft for 1D

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

this is my input 1D array:

```
 [13.9284, 14.5602, 15.5242, 16.4924, 17.4642, 18.2483, 19.2354, 20.2237, 21.095, 21.0238, 22, 23, 24.0208, 23.0868, 24.1868, 25.1794, 26.0768, 27.074, 28.0713, 27.074, 26.0768, 25.0799, 24.0208, 25, 26, 27, 28, 27.0185, 28.0713, 29.0689, 30.0167, 30, 30, 30.0167, 31, 32, 33.0151, 34.0147, 33, 32, 31.0161, 32.0624, 33.1361, 34.0588, 35.0571, 36.0139, 36, 37, 38.0132, 37.054, 37.1214, 36.2215, 35.2278, 34.1321, 33.2415, 33.3766, 34.5254, 35.5106, 36.6742, 37.6563, 36.6742, 35.5106, 34.5254, 33.3766, 32.3883, 31.257, 30.1496, 29.2746, 29.4279, 30.5941, 30.8058, 30.0832, 29.1204, 28.1603, 27.2029, 25.9615, 25.2982, 24.0416, 23.0868, 22.1359, 21.1896, 20.2485, 19.3132, 18.3848, 17.088, 16.1555, 15.2315, 14.3178, 13.4164, 12.53, 11.1803, 10.2956, 9.43398, 8.60233, 7.81025, 6.40312, 5.65685, 5, 4.47214, 4.12311, 4, 3, 3.16228, 3.60555, 4.24264, 5, 5.83095, 6.7082, 7.28011, 8.24621, 9.21954, 10.198, 11.0454, 12.0416, 13.0384, 14.0357, 15.0333, 16.0312, 17.0294, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28.0179, 29.0172, 30.0167, 31.0161, 32.0156, 33.0151, 34.0147, 35.0143, 36.0555, 37.054, 38.0526, 39.0512, 40.05, 41.1096, 42.107, 43.1045, 44.1022, 45.0999, 46.0977, 47.0956, 48.1664, 49.163, 50.1597, 51.1566, 52.2398, 53.2353, 54.231, 55.2268, 56.2228, 55.2268, 54.231, 53.2353, 52.2398, 51.2445, 50.2494, 49.2544, 48.2597, 47.2652, 46.2709, 45.2769, 44.2832, 43.2897, 42.2966, 41.3038, 40.3113, 39.3192, 38.3275, 37.3363, 36.3456, 35.3553, 34.3657, 33.3766, 32.3883, 31.4006, 30.4138, 29.4279, 28.4429, 27.4591, 26.4764, 25.4951, 24.5153, 23.5372, 22.561, 21.587, 20.6155, 19.6469, 18.6815, 17.72, 16.7631, 15.8114, 14.8661, 13.9284, 13, 12.083, 11.1803, 10.2956, 9.43398, 8.60233, 7.81025, 7.07107, 6.40312, 5.83095, 5.38516, 5.09902, 5, 5, 5.09902, 5.38516, 5.83095, 6.40312, 7.07107, 7.81025, 8.60233, 9.43398, 10.2956, 11.1803, 12.083, 13]
```

when I run 
Matlab `fft` I get different results than

answer from Matlab:

```
5850.44082000000 + 0.00000000000000i    -236.195108992328 + 494.327104308963i   -1601.71373056680 - 1257.19679210623i   401.270621054570 - 54.8348065835625i    58.6362849360901 - 163.991208417496i    -81.1618489916308 - 60.6727729546051i   98.2137509701359 - 178.874979649065i    8.75660326872264 + 31.1059211928010i    -14.4396596622584 - 7.65407579243336i   -9.18663229218099 - 27.1997908482849i   32.5503165463479 + 24.3192745247901i    -31.1219011708661 + 25.7860663846281i   2.95031666949167 + 6.15041271891396i    15.5915878000708 + 7.44141735494909i    6.97702383662843 + 35.5170021796418i    23.6281937003968 - 21.1006242353996i    5.97648257401926 - 39.6138615794895i    -33.0032997489133 + 1.30076978156147i   -15.0418122371750 + 24.6819515735041i   31.1393323965219 - 10.0379855452569i    -8.54814236721161 - 24.2416895900915i   -39.1574989954314 + 6.70015288183043i   -5.60660423183304 + 23.6679501739800i   19.1780240882932 + 15.5704394051741i    1.30717784406095 + 3.68504588500404i    7.45795750406563 + 3.39486331858465i    17.5245792950556 - 4.31294325456059i    2.41873595069340 - 7.44453173664043i    -6.00947311352358 - 12.1313710088946i   -4.18154377130777 - 2.50225243762004i   -2.20651365633251 + 4.72665264429753i   -1.72270341112623 + 0.197689181530038i  3.48935944436198 - 8.66327988659334i    -11.8221389770113 - 2.73492738484021i   -13.4251149477799 + 12.7213800072862i   3.73623581925574 + 12.7809120584468i    13.9007662712349 + 8.74121680636068i    6.24770455302712 - 2.00106833739501i    6.18955793386744 - 1.78052956088457i    9.37882547144118 - 10.4387804557484i    -10.2820486114914 - 7.56460553957821i   -6.91793379409868 + 3.37859410905941i   2.26246595365120 + 2.85055700831106i    2.97164192031584 + 1.19638197424677i    -2.32764734219557 - 3.52146253780298i   -0.128456276053257 + 0.371511723725504i 2.51404210613061 - 0.368321502067278i   -3.36759807322456 - 1.99977119992005i   -0.550861771421822 - 0.781259371882626i 0.654734330528342 - 1.10909753428241i   -5.10226403227105 - 0.649609303524812i  -4.35743957552811 + 2.03780871572405i   0.789562920892216 + 5.02843929868241i   1.31772372300086 + 3.20064305370176i    -0.140064442432518 + 0.715606830659397i 2.55731297616605 + 1.22415928937412i    0.972383057822540 + 1.11452954184361i   -1.09766497930718 + 0.128751181670111i  0.295033690905171 + 0.753971522354846i  1.55444641432210 + 3.35145255172278i    0.374562941292385 + 2.08937979612806i   5.29852099293259 + 1.37829167261507i    5.54859012001244 - 3.21257680351025i    -1.07668822076172 - 3.30955388709968i   -1.37257720079793 - 2.44245043665786i   1.40536606890888 + 1.66440564981678i    2.49435403989193 - 2.58415130217770i    -3.28563738557140 - 4.05477826915994i   -0.518407813348183 + 0.131067263982409i -2.04925759851836 - 0.262283316140675i  -2.41969646059706 + 0.777798355648820i  -0.134139765532215 + 0.907106120270047i 0.730399953450643 + 1.65851073839491i   -1.45678885233597 - 1.16372102129882i   -2.20160324624550 + 1.32325219820590i   0.579604238352069 + 3.38240693896227i   0.831075445733614 + 3.24321494006862i   4.28901429023598 - 0.0874581930640304i  1.49823315525401 - 2.39040184090840i    -0.377513297736293 + 1.16391842543968i  2.06813869338537 - 1.19345092081081i    2.05985213152420 - 2.22716482633267i    -0.442563051798736 - 3.60274864824367i  -5.60740416812049 - 2.10873191433014i   -2.28409332116379 + 3.25751007842877i   0.433042603344951 + 3.05868696142239i   1.02072812804223 + 1.96653338929739i    1.84085146695848 - 0.923985120389667i   0.388629240309292 + 0.838212051807965i  1.17786879322356 + 0.400582810627874i   0.259566861526970 - 1.80532655327674i   0.372659878189257 + 0.0860665525151383i -0.467279393929562 + 0.0194961351504794i    -0.788639270316992 - 0.728110745822363i -0.525425582048058 + 1.05458284528174i  1.09457353336624 + 2.35618849514349i    1.29718434477957 - 0.926336813481122i   0.654663687830375 - 0.243309093614304i  1.46292093798042 + 0.514645032758256i   1.57935027555005 - 0.946259927194781i   0.997945072809900 - 3.95889770752841i   -2.11126597496163 - 1.85525696046438i   -2.85375151259268 - 0.665127010849972i  -3.67649131275672 + 1.49357708053631i   2.02842018202423 + 3.43084304311646i    0.587989734036455 - 0.665601892824327i  -0.885597237730284 - 0.276649300905060i -0.285389790393298 - 0.374323003019116i -1.75323182180390 + 2.12902138070610i   -0.394442022274234 + 1.59875943868965i  0.770938958112609 + 1.84913363734508i   1.83828912016749 + 2.31866799695042i    1.02615442076382 + 0.996282806003860i   3.01830600098366 + 0.528644305273687i   3.01830600098366 - 0.528644305273687i   1.02615442076382 - 0.996282806003860i   1.83828912016749 - 2.31866799695042i    0.770938958112609 - 1.84913363734508i   -0.394442022274234 - 1.59875943868965i  -1.75323182180390 - 2.12902138070610i   -0.285389790393298 + 0.374323003019116i -0.885597237730284 + 0.276649300905060i 0.587989734036455 + 0.665601892824327i  2.02842018202423 - 3.43084304311646i    -3.67649131275672 - 1.49357708053631i   -2.85375151259268 + 0.665127010849972i  -2.11126597496163 + 1.85525696046438i   0.997945072809900 + 3.95889770752841i   1.57935027555005 + 0.946259927194781i   1.46292093798042 - 0.514645032758256i   0.654663687830375 + 0.243309093614304i  1.29718434477957 + 0.926336813481122i   1.09457353336624 - 2.35618849514349i    -0.525425582048058 - 1.05458284528174i  -0.788639270316992 + 0.728110745822363i -0.467279393929562 - 0.0194961351504794i    0.372659878189257 - 0.0860665525151383i 0.259566861526970 + 1.80532655327674i   1.17786879322356 - 0.400582810627874i   0.388629240309292 - 0.838212051807965i  1.84085146695848 + 0.923985120389667i   1.02072812804223 - 1.96653338929739i    0.433042603344951 - 3.05868696142239i   -2.28409332116379 - 3.25751007842877i   -5.60740416812049 + 2.10873191433014i   -0.442563051798736 + 3.60274864824367i  2.05985213152420 + 2.22716482633267i    2.06813869338537 + 1.19345092081081i    -0.377513297736293 - 1.16391842543968i  1.49823315525401 + 2.39040184090840i    4.28901429023598 + 0.0874581930640304i  0.831075445733614 - 3.24321494006862i   0.579604238352069 - 3.38240693896227i   -2.20160324624550 - 1.32325219820590i   -1.45678885233597 + 1.16372102129882i   0.730399953450643 - 1.65851073839491i   -0.134139765532215 - 0.907106120270047i -2.41969646059706 - 0.777798355648820i  -2.04925759851836 + 0.262283316140675i  -0.518407813348183 - 0.131067263982409i -3.28563738557140 + 4.05477826915994i   2.49435403989193 + 2.58415130217770i    1.40536606890888 - 1.66440564981678i    -1.37257720079793 + 2.44245043665786i   -1.07668822076172 + 3.30955388709968i   5.54859012001244 + 3.21257680351025i    5.29852099293259 - 1.37829167261507i    0.374562941292385 - 2.08937979612806i   1.55444641432210 - 3.35145255172278i    0.295033690905171 - 0.753971522354846i  -1.09766497930718 - 0.128751181670111i  0.972383057822540 - 1.11452954184361i   2.55731297616605 - 1.22415928937412i    -0.140064442432518 - 0.715606830659397i 1.31772372300086 - 3.20064305370176i    0.789562920892216 - 5.02843929868241i   -4.35743957552811 - 2.03780871572405i   -5.10226403227105 + 0.649609303524812i  0.654734330528342 + 1.10909753428241i   -0.550861771421822 + 0.781259371882626i -3.36759807322456 + 1.99977119992005i   2.51404210613061 + 0.368321502067278i   -0.128456276053257 - 0.371511723725504i -2.32764734219557 + 3.52146253780298i   2.97164192031584 - 1.19638197424677i    2.26246595365120 - 2.85055700831106i    -6.91793379409868 - 3.37859410905941i   -10.2820486114914 + 7.56460553957821i   9.37882547144118 + 10.4387804557484i    6.18955793386744 + 1.78052956088457i    6.24770455302712 + 2.00106833739501i    13.9007662712349 - 8.74121680636068i    3.73623581925574 - 12.7809120584468i    -13.4251149477799 - 12.7213800072862i   -11.8221389770113 + 2.73492738484021i   3.48935944436198 + 8.66327988659334i    -1.72270341112623 - 0.197689181530038i  -2.20651365633251 - 4.72665264429753i   -4.18154377130777 + 2.50225243762004i   -6.00947311352358 + 12.1313710088946i   2.41873595069340 + 7.44453173664043i    17.5245792950556 + 4.31294325456059i    7.45795750406563 - 3.39486331858465i    1.30717784406095 - 3.68504588500404i    19.1780240882932 - 15.5704394051741i    -5.60660423183304 - 23.6679501739800i   -39.1574989954314 - 6.70015288183043i   -8.54814236721161 + 24.2416895900915i   31.1393323965219 + 10.0379855452569i    -15.0418122371750 - 24.6819515735041i   -33.0032997489133 - 1.30076978156147i   5.97648257401926 + 39.6138615794895i    23.6281937003968 + 21.1006242353996i    6.97702383662843 - 35.5170021796418i    15.5915878000708 - 7.44141735494909i    2.95031666949167 - 6.15041271891396i    -31.1219011708661 - 25.7860663846281i   32.5503165463479 - 24.3192745247901i    -9.18663229218099 + 27.1997908482849i   -14.4396596622584 + 7.65407579243336i   8.75660326872264 - 31.1059211928010i    98.2137509701359 + 178.874979649065i    -81.1618489916308 + 60.6727729546051i   58.6362849360901 + 163.991208417496i    401.270621054570 + 54.8348065835625i    -1601.71373056680 + 1257.19679210623i   -236.195108992328 - 494.327104308963i
```

openCV 2.4.10:

```
cv::vector<float> distanceF; // this is the type of the vector
cv::dft(distanceF, ff, cv::DFT_ROWS|cv::DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT);
```

OpenCV output please note that some of the values are the same:

```
[5850.4424, 0, -236.19542, 494.32721, -1601.7139, -1257.1968, 401.27112, -54.834793, 58.635941, -163.99118, -81.161819, -60.672802, 98.213882, -178.8752, 8.7567081, 31.105858, -14.439482, -7.6539149, -9.1864853, -27.199965, 32.550457, 24.319056, -31.122013, 25.786121, 2.9505329, 6.1505966, 15.59177, 7.4411783, 6.9766369, 35.51675, 23.628296, -21.100199, 5.9758949, -39.613434, -33.00349, 1.3006741, -15.041353, 24.681818, 31.139578, -10.038104, -8.5481758, -24.24147, -39.157513, 6.7004414, -5.6067162, 23.668552, 19.177927, 15.570613, 1.3069649, 3.6849215, 7.4576416, 3.3949444, 17.524834, -4.3131351, 2.4190979, -7.4447069, -6.009819, -12.131269, -4.1815758, -2.5021544, -2.2066612, 4.7267613, -1.722599, 0.1980657, 3.4889717, -8.66294, -11.822751, -2.7352583, -13.425085, 12.721531, 3.7364502, 12.780836, 13.900464, 8.7409039, 6.2476082, -2.000788, 6.1896486, -1.7802718, 9.3790874, -10.438701, -10.282202, -7.5648155, -6.9182959, 3.3786888, 2.2623367, 2.8504691, 2.9716797, 1.1957676, -2.3280506, -3.521215, -0.12844467, 0.37162167, 2.513998, -0.36863309, -3.3680859, -1.9997617, -0.55117607, -0.78108609, 0.6547966, -1.1083429, -5.1021919, -0.64962733, -4.3571014, 2.0373371, 0.78962708, 5.0286837, 1.3172665, 3.2008133, -0.14001274, 0.71585965, 2.5574074, 1.2240793, 0.97222137, 1.1142333, -1.0971603, 0.12921375, 0.29561615, 0.75393069, 1.5542717, 3.3511853, 0.37465286, 2.0893302, 5.2984409, 1.3784981, 5.548686, -3.2126107, -1.076519, -3.3098588, -1.3726921, -2.4427652, 1.4058294, 1.6643414, 2.4948006, -2.5840356, -3.2862215, -4.0548897, -0.51816654, 0.13079435, -2.0494299, -0.26226592, -2.4197426, 0.77750373, -0.13409233, 0.90709144, 0.73083496, 1.6584089, -1.4566784, -1.163747, -2.2017193, 1.3230393, 0.57952499, 3.3821714, 0.83114338, 3.2429562, 4.2885866, -0.087527037, 1.4980612, -2.3904862, -0.37744904, 1.1637971, 2.0684986, -1.1937973, 2.0592871, -2.227041, -0.44268799, -3.6024194, -5.6071653, -2.1089995, -2.2843628, 3.2571955, 0.43229103, 3.0588517, 1.0210943, 1.9662709, 1.8409662, -0.9237324, 0.3887701, 0.83835888, 1.1778173, 0.40068072, 0.2591362, -1.805531, 0.37266827, 0.085778832, -0.46706057, 0.019422591, -0.78862524, -0.72800255, -0.52543736, 1.0548751, 1.0942721, 2.3556924, 1.2972126, -0.92645401, 0.65454626, -0.24292475, 1.4631515, 0.51448888, 1.5789657, -0.94608289, 0.99792957, -3.9589138, -2.1106853, -1.8556111, -2.8534913, -0.66516978, -3.6764612, 1.493674, 2.0280688, 3.4307818, 0.58782125, -0.66583544, -0.88579464, -0.27679062, -0.28537679, -0.37455428, -1.7532051, 2.1291695, -0.39484131, 1.598603, 0.77090323, 1.8497298, 1.8382895, 2.3185685, 1.0264703, 0.99646896, 3.0183427, 0.52932495, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008]
```

Can you please tell me if there is a way to get the same result as matlab?
this number ***-4.3160208e+008, -4.3160208e+008*** appears over and over. is this a conversion problems?

Comment: can you show the different results?

Comment: @Kornel I have added flag DFT_ROWS and also added the results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are taking the `fft` of real data, therefore the Fourier coffees have the Hermite symmetry `c(k)=conjugate(c(-k))`, where `k` is the index of the coefficient, or the wavenumber if want to say so.

Matlab arranges the output like this

```
[c(0),c(1),c(2),...,c(N/2),c(-N/2),c(-N/2+1),...,c(-1)]
```

in other words it puts the negative part of the spectrum next to the positive one.

Now, due to the aforementioned symmetry of real-data Fourier transform, it is redundant to represent both halfs of the Fourier spectrum (one is just the complex conjugate of the other). Matlab does it anyway, but it doesn't seem to be the case for OpenCV. If you note, the weird number -4.3160208e+008 appears on the second half of the OpenCV output, and it seems to me that this is just some sort of dummy padding.
Basically, you should just disregard this second half of the output, the real output is just the first half.

Comment: @caludv so you are saying, that matlab return 227 complex numbers and i need to disregard half of them? and open cv returns 454 numbers which are 227 complex numbers (1 for real and one for imaginary) and i should disregard half of those as well)?

Comment: Matlab output is all good, with redundancy, because it contains both halfs of the spectrum. It is up to you to decide if you need to use both or just the first half (for better efficiency) in the following computations. With open cv you have to trow away the second half (all the -4.3160208e+008's) because it is just rubbish. And yes, open cv stores the result in a 2*N real array (real,imag,real,imag,...) whereas Matlab uses a N complex array.

Comment: @caludv how can I see one value of the output matrix from openCV DFT?

Comment: how do i get from ff matrix which is a cv::mat which i don't know it's type after DFT the value at location 0 for example? I usually use something like ff.at<float>(0); but it doesn't work after the DFT

Comment: @Caludev so openCV restores only one half of the spectrum? Can I make   it return both halves?

Answer (score 3):

for future reference this is tested at is bit accurate to matlab's results for 1D

```
    cv::Mat ff;
    cv::dft(distanceF, ff, cv::DFT_ROWS|cv::DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT);

    //Make place for both the complex and the real values
    cv::Mat planes[] = {cv::Mat::zeros(distanceF.size(),1, CV_32F), cv::Mat::zeros(distanceF.size(),1, CV_32F)};
    cv::split(ff, planes);                   // planes[0] = Re(DFT(I), planes[1] = Im(DFT(I))

    int m = planes[0].cols;
    int pivot = ceil(m/2);
    //duplicate FFT results with Complex conjugate in order to get exact matlab results

    for (int i = pivot + 1, k = pivot; i < planes[1].cols; i++, k--)
    {
         planes[1].at<float>(i) = planes[1].at<float>(k) * -1; 
         planes[0].at<float>(i) = planes[0].at<float>(k);
    }
```