# OpenCV: Detecting seizure-inducing lights in a video?

Tags: c++, opencv, video, video-processing, light

I have been working on an algorithm which can detect seizure-inducing strobe lights in a video.

Currently, my code returns virtually every frame as capable of causing a seizure (3Hz flashes).

My code calculates the relative luminance of each pixel and sees how many times the luminance goes up then down, etc. or down then up, etc. by more than 10% within any given second.

Is there any way to do this without comparing each individual pixel within a second of each other and that only returns the correct frames.

An example of what I am trying to emulate: https://trace.umd.edu/peat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common approach to solving this type of problems is to convert the frames to grayscale and then construct a cube containing frames from a 1 to 3 seconds time interval. From this cube, you can extract the time-varying characteristics of either individual pixels (noisy), or blocks (recommended). The resulting 1D curves can first be observed manually to see if they actually show the 3Hz variation that you are looking for (sometimes, these variations are either lost or distorted because of the camera's auto exposure settings). If you can see it, they you should be able to use FFT to isolate and detect it automatically.

Comment: This helps a lot! But why use a FFT instead of a DFT since the grey-scale image brightness values are of a discrete type?

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I wanted to say DFT.

Comment: Hey! I've tried this approach, but I am having trouble actually applying the DFT and making sense of it. I am new to the DFT, but can it be used on a curve of average luminance values of each block instead of the pure images (type Mat) in each block?

Comment: The idea is to use DFT on the curve of average luminance values of each block. Not sure if OpenCV's DFT is directly usable on a 1D array, but we can try a different library if it does not work. If it is too hard to get to work, you can also normalize the array by subtracting the mean, manually observe some results, and then calculate cross-ratio to see if that works.

Comment: How would one calculate the DFT/FFT of a 1D array of luminance values. Let's say one of the 64x64 blocks in a one second time-frame have luminance values [100, 120, 130, 90, 80 ... etc.] across the n frames in that time. How would I extract frequency/perform an FFT?

Comment: There is an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29232639/opencv-dft-vs-matlab-fft-for-1d#29234391

Comment: Alright, it worked! But what do the values mean? Are these the amplitudes for the frequency spectrum analysis of the array? If so, how can I find the 3Hz frequency from this?

Comment: I haven't used DFT for this, but the easiest way to do this is to calculate the DFT of y = sin(2*pi*f*t) where t corresponds to the frame rate. and look for the places where the peaks appear. A textbook should give a better solution, just that I am not sure if I can find time to find one.

Comment: An even better way to do this is to obtain a few samples of seizure inducing flashes and observe their DFT distributions. Once you make a model using the average and standard deviation values of these two, it will take care of camera noise and automatic gain control effects.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the image to grayscale. Break the image up into blocks, maybe 16x16 or 64x64 or larger (experiment to see what works). Take the average luminance of each block over a minimum of 2/3 seconds. Create a wave of luminance over time. Do an fft on this wave and look for a minimum energy threshold around 3Hz.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! How would one calculate the DFT/FFT of a 1D array of luminance values. Let's say one of the 64x64 blocks in a one second time-frame have luminance values [100, 120, 130, 90, 80 ... etc.] across the n frames in that time. How would I extract frequency/perform an FFT?